# How to convert list to dictionary using key but do not include key as element

Tags: c#

I've got the following `linq` query which works fine:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.DocumentTypes.Select(c => new
{
    RowId = c.RowId,
    Id = c.Id,
    IsDocumentType = c.IsDocumentType
}).ToDictionary(x => x.RowId));
```

and as you can see, I'm setting my dictionary's key to the RowId but I can only get this to work if I include the RowId as an element that is returned.

Is there a way to achieve the same result without having to include the RowId as a returned element?

Thanks.

Comment: you should put c.Id , that is also unique right ?

Comment: What *do* you want to be the key in the dictionary, if you don't want it to be the row ID?

Comment: I want the RowId to be the key alright but I don't want to return it as an element. I just want to return Id and IsDocumentType and assign each of these to a RowId. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: c.Id is not unique unfortunately. That's why I had to introduce the RowId in my code. The c.Id returns data from a Union query which returns data from 2 different sources but are assigned to the Id field.

Comment: The converter isn't that smart. It can only handle strings with two fields without help. Yout might need to define sth. like `Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, bool>>` and pass this as the target type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload of the [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx) method that allows you to specify how the value is constructed. For example, you probably want something like this (note this also removes the need for the `Select`):

```
var data = this.DocumentTypes
    .ToDictionary(
        dt => dt.RowId,
        dt => new { dt.Id, dt.IsDocumentType })); //<< Here we are creating a new anonymous
                                                  //   type to use as the value

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Comment: Super! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you.